# WSO2 IS - SAML external identity provider - how to use specific key/certyficate

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I need to use SAML external identity provider with WSO2.
To do it, I recived 2 key/certificates (one for signing, one for encryption).
I created key stores with those key/certificates.

My problem is:

How to specify that those certificates have to be used when sign/encrypt requests to
external identity provider?

I have "checked" `Enable Authentication Request Signing` but i can see no way of pointing to specific
key.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using Wso2 as a SAML service provider. You have an external IDP. By default in the identity server the request signing happens from the private key in default Keystore. You can export its certificate as follows

> keytool -export -keystore wso2carbon.jks -alias wso2carbon -file
> wso2carbon.crt
>
> openssl x509 -inform der -in wso2carbon.crt -out wso2carbon.pem

This certificate should be provided to the IdP so that it can validate the signature.

If you need a custom key to sign you may need to create a new keystore and configure that as the primary keystore in wso2 identity server.

Comment: I received those keys/certs from provider (this installation is for concept approval).
One of cert has `X509v3 Key Usage: Digital Signature`, 
second has `X509v3 Key Usage: Key Agreement`

This provider requires usage of separate keys:
first for request signing, second for assertion encryption.

How to specify separate key/cert that should be used with assertion encrtyption?